# Error in creating time series chart in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I'm trying to generate a chart but keep getting this error whenever I run the code:

```
Error generating chart: Error in map(ID=2000): Collection.filter, argument 'collection': Invalid type. Expected type: FeatureCollection. Actual type: Image<[b1]>
```

I'm not sure which line of the code the error is referring to but this is my current code:

```
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("...").filter(ee.Filter.eq("NAME","..."));

//use 10% as a threshold for forest
//function to create a image collection with forest layers 
var calcForest = function(y){
  var forest = ee.ImageCollection(y).filter(ee.Filter.gt("b1",10)).set("system:time_start",y.get("system:time_start"));
  return forest;
}; 
 
//table2 is an ImageCollection of tcc from 2000 to 2022 previously imported
var forest = table2.map(calcForest);

// Define the chart and print it to the console.
//chart for forest pixel area 
var chart =
    ui.Chart.image.series({
          imageCollection: forest,
          region: aoi,
          reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
          scale: 300,
          xProperty: 'system:time_start'
        })
        .setSeriesNames(['forest'])
        .setOptions({
          title: 'Date',
          hAxis: {title: 'Date', titleTextStyle: {italic: true, bold: true}},
          vAxis: {
            title: 'forest pixel area',
            titleTextStyle: {italic: true, bold: true}
          },
          lineWidth: 5,
          colors: ['c51b7d'],
          curveType: 'function'
        });
           
print(chart);
```